# Im using Flatpicker i wanted to disable the past time This is what I have currently

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datetimepicker

```
var timewsd = document.getElementById("current_datetime").value ;
            var currentdate = "";





            let roundDate = (date = new Date(timewsd), roundToMinutes = 60) => {
                const ms = 1000 * 60 * roundToMinutes;
                return new Date(Math.ceil(date.getTime() / ms) * ms);
            };

            var current_time = new Date(timewsd).getHours()+":"+new Date(timewsd).getMinutes();

            const date = new Date(timewsd);

            // if(current_time > '16:30'){
            //     currentdate =  setDate(timewsd.getDate() + 1);
            // }else{
            //     currentdate = document.getElementById("current_datetime").value;
            // }



            $("#kt_datepicker_2").flatpickr({
                minDate: "today",
                minuteIncrement: 1,
                enableTime: true,
                minTime :current_time
            });
```

However when selecting a future date the time limits to the current time for the futiure date too.

https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `minDate: "today"` replace it with `minDate: new Date()` & also remove `minTime` and you will get your desired output.

Below, I have provided a live example for your reference.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Select a Date and Time</h1>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Select date and time">
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
    <script>
        flatpickr("#datepicker", {
            enableTime: true,
            minuteIncrement: 1,
            minDate: new Date()
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable **past time** and **past date** both then follow this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- flatpicker CSS CDN  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <h4>Select a Date and Time</h4>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Select date and time">

    <!-- flatpicker JS CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
    <script>
        const now = new Date();   // get current date and time
        var currentHour = now.getHours();   // get current hours
        var currentMinute = now.getMinutes();   // get current minutes
        flatpickr("#datepicker", {
            enableTime: true,
            minuteIncrement: 1,
            minDate: new Date(),
            minTime: `${currentHour}:${currentMinute}`,
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to disable the date only then remove **minTime** element from a **flatpicker** config.